# Why in the next code c = 1?

Tags: c

Why in the next code `c = 1` ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 65537;
    char c = (char)i;
    printf("c = %d\n",c); /* why c =1 */
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: What do you expect it to be?

Comment: Because 65537 is binary 10000000000000001.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg How is this type-cast related to endianness?! It will result in 1 both on big-endian, and on little-endian.

Comment: no. I need explanation why c = 1 , why (char)I = int I 65537 = c=1

Comment: Yes, the comments are actually explaining this behavior. See the answers for more details.

Comment: @IgorR. - actually it's implementation defined how `char c = (char)i;` will behave if the value of `i` can't be represented by `char`.

Comment: @Michael Burr Yes, that's correct. But neither in Standard nor in practice it depends on endianness.

Answer (score 7):

65537 is 0x10001 (in hexadecimal, 10000000000000001 in binary). If you cast this value to `char`, which is only one byte long, you will only be taking the lowest (least-significant) byte from 0x1001, which is 0x01 = 1 in decimal.

Answer (score 5):

Char stores only 1 byte. By assigning `c` to an `int` value, only the lowest byte is assigned.

65537 = 256 * 256 + 1.

Hence `c = 1.`

Answer (score 4):

The char type is only 8 bits long, while int has 32 bits.
When you assign an int variable to a char, the value is cut to just the 8 least significant bits.

65537 is in binary `10000000 000000001`

So, the least significant byte is `00000001`

Comment: *"while int has 32 bits"* This actually depends on architecture.

Comment: @m0skit0 well, actually the whole behavior that OP encountered is platform-dependent. Because on some platforms `char` can have much more than 8 bit, so 65537 won't be truncated.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.

@IgorR, I thought char was 1 byte long by definition in C. On a platform that char is larger than 8 bits, how would I create something 1 byte long?

Comment: `char` is byte (i.e. the Standard requires that sizeof(char) == 1), but byte is not necessarily 8 bits. Eg., on systems where `char` has 9 bits, there's no type having exactly 8 bits (with no padding).

Answer (score 0):

This for casting from int to char:
    int i = 65537;
    char c = (char)i;

First four bytes are casted here from 10000000000000001: this is why it coming as 1
if you use 65539 (10000000000000011), char will be 3